# Click event not working on Samsung S7 instead it does quick google search

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

So I have a strange problem regarding the, play icon on click event on Samsung S7.
On other phones everything is working correctly but, on Samsung S7 I have strange issue, so when user clicks on icon it doesn't recognize the click event, it just opens google search.

Here is my html

```
<div id="video-blurb" class="et_pb_blurb et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light et_pb_text_align_left  et_pb_blurb_0 et_pb_blurb_position_top">
                <div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
                    <div class="et_pb_main_blurb_image"><span class="et-pb-icon et-waypoint et_pb_animation_off et-animated" style="color: #23282d;">I</span></div>
                    <div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
                        <h4>Play Video</h4>

<div id="cover-video">
<span class="closer">X</span><br>
<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 56.25%;"><iframe id="youtube-vid" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AoHDeBBx4og?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
</div>

                    </div>
                </div> <!-- .et_pb_blurb_content -->
            </div>
```

And also Js

```
$('#video-blurb .et-pb-icon').click(function(ev) {
$('#cover-video').fadeIn();
$(videoBlure).attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/AoHDeBBx4og?wmode=opaque');
$('#youtube-vid')[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

I hope you understood the question
Here is screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you share with us the console from your device to view if this returns an error?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, everything is clear in console

Comment: This only appears on this device?